# How can I get a list of all DLCs I own in a list on Steam?

Tags: steam

I don't want to look through every game I own (200+ games). Is there a way to pull up a list that shows every owned DLC?

Comment: You can add a showcase to your steam profile in which you can see how many DLC's you own. It should be the game showcase. This doesn't anwer your question, but it might help you.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to see all games' DLC at once. You will have to go to each game specifically to see.

From [Steam's support page on finding owned DLC](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2668-CFOM-1881):

> DLC owned by your account can be viewed in your library. From the Library tab in the Steam Client, select a game and the DLC section will show if you own DLC and if it's been installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to a game's store page, and it will show you the DLC for that certain game. Blue markings on the left side of an entry will signal that you own that DLC.